# Jquery's same function for different events

Tags: javascript, jquery

MY code is like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){     
        nodeClick(elm = '');   
    });

function nodeClick()
{ 
    if(elm != ''){
        var obj = '';
    }else{
        obj = $('.hitarea')
    }

    obj.live('click',function(){   
    $(this).addClass('something');
    $(this).attr('something',1);
    //lots of this reference are here


    });

}
```

if elm variable is empty i  need to call the click function automatically ie  with out click.how can i trigger that function with out click

Comment: Wait, what? Can you explain this?

Comment: I want to trigger the click function automatically when elm variable is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty confused by the wording, but to trigger a `click` event, use `.trigger()`:

```
obj.trigger('click');
```

Comment: I read the question before the edit. This is how you trigger a click event.

Comment: Will it(trigger) work with live elements..i mean the elements are created dynamically with ajax

Answer (score 0):

The function nodeclick in not taking any parameter and you passing it. Add parameter in it and then pass it in the call like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){     
     elm = '';
        nodeClick();   
    });

function nodeClick(elm)
{ 
    if(elm != ''){
        var obj = '';
    }else{
        obj = $('.hitarea')
    }

    obj.live('click',function(){   
    $(this).addClass('something');
    $(this).attr('something',1);
    //lots of this reference are there are

        /****
          if elm variable is empty i  need to call these function automatically ie        with out click.how can i trigger that function with out click
       ******/
    });

   obj.click(); //You can call click event handler like this


}
```

Comment: will this automatically trigger the click function when elm variable is empty ?? i dont think so

Comment: This could cause click of obj, obj.click();